# Error: Function not declared in this scope. Help?

Tags: c++

Here is (part of) my code:

```
...

 Node<char*>* nodes[count2];//array of pointers to last level
    nodes[0] = f1.rootPtr;
    processInput(input, f1.rootPtr, nodes, 0, count2);
    //I get an error that says this function is not declared in this scope.

    return input;

}

void processInput(istream& input, Node<char*>* node, Node<char*>** nodeArray,
        int level, int& count)
{
    //variables
    Node<char*>* aNode = new Node<char*>();
    char charArray[150];
...
```

When I run the program I get this:

```
Forest.cpp: In function 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Forest<char*>&)':
Forest.cpp:93:53: error: 'processInput' was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Forest.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
```

Here is part of the header file:

```
template<typename NODETYPE> class Forest{

    /*
     * builds a forests consisting of the first and second forest reference
     */
    template<NODETYPE>
    friend Forest& operator+(Forest<NODETYPE>& f1, Forest<NODETYPE>& f2);

    /*
     * insert into the output stream a preorder traversal of the input forest
     */
    template<NODETYPE>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Forest<NODETYPE>& f1);

    /*
    * extracts a forest from the input stream and builds it for the forest argument variable name
    */
    //template<NODETYPE>
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& file, Forest<char*>& f1);

    /*
     *Used with istream to go through input
     */
    //template<NODETYPE>
    void processInput(istream& input, Node<char*>* nodeBefore, Node<char*> ** nodeArray,
        int levelBefore, int& count);

public:
    Forest(){

..
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get that error. Any advice?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried what you said, but it still isn't working.  I'm using templates though, so maybe that's where my problem lies?

Header:

template //SHOULD I KEEP THIS?? When I take it out it also doesn't work
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& file, Forest& f1);

private:
 void processInput(istream& input, Node* node, Node ** nodeArray,
        int level, int& count);

.cpp file:

template
istream& operator>> (istream &input, Forest& f1){
//code
...
processInput(input, f1.rootPtr, nodes, 0, count2);
//ERROR: Unable to resolve identifier processInput 
}

/**
  * Processes the input
 */
void Forest::processInput(istream& input, Node* node, Node** nodeArray, int level, int& count){
    //code

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix your class functions with the name of their class, do you do that currently? If not, the compiler thinks that they are free functions.

For example,

```
void processInput(istream& input, Node<char*>* node, Node<char*>** nodeArray,
    int level, int& count) {
    // ...code...
}
```

should be

```
void Forest::processInput(istream& input, Node<char*>* node, Node<char*>** nodeArray,
    int level, int& count) {
    // ...code...
}
```

Comment: Of course, only the definition, not the declaration inside the class itself.